# Trying to get LARGE to output a letter that represents a number vs the number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some help and have not been able to find an answer as of yet.  I'll do my best to explain...the spreadsheet will list a set of numbers with a letter above each number.  The spreadsheet needs to pull the letter that corresponds to the number.  I need it to pull the top five numbers, but, only represent the numbers by their letter code.
If two numbers match, it needs to pull the different letter codes for each number.  For example, say I have the number 4500 that's in my table twice.  The first time, it's under the letter G and the second time it's under the letter J.  I want the spreadsheet to show both the G and J...not just G.  I'm attaching a picture to hopefully show more clearly what I'm needing.  I have tried using Index/Match, but, the formula I'm using only wants to show G twice.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cliff[spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVzd4.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you tell us what the correlation of `LARGE` in the title is related to the question? Or share your formula so we can see what you currently have?

Comment: I am struggling to understand your requirements in your question when the data set would not call for `G` **and** `J` to be given in the same box. Ok 4500 is in both columns but on different lines and therefore if the criteria in `A8` is followed you would not want `G` **and** `J` in the same box. In fact 4500 is actually in a large number of columns.

Comment: I thought my question was pretty clear...I apologize that it was not.  Basically, the LARGE needed to pull the top 5 largest values and assign a "letter" code instead of the actual value.  The problem I ran in to was that the formula I was using would run into an issue when it came to a cell that had the exact same number in it.  For example, if cells G2 and K2 had 4500 in them, the formula was only outputting the letter from cell G1 (which corresponded to the number that was in cell G2)...it wouldn't output the letter that was in cell K1.  I don't remember the actual formula though.

Comment: I think it was {=index($g$1:$s$6,match(large($g2:$s2),0))}...or something similar.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formula which you can use:
`=INDEX($G$1:$S$1,MATCH(LARGE($G2:$S2-COLUMN($G2:$S2)/100,COLUMN()),$G2:$S2-COLUMN($G2:$S2)/100,0))`

this modifies the values in each column to make it unique.

This is an array formula, so you need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing it.

[image]

Comment: That works...However, if you add a column in front of A (to make a new column...say with names)...meaning, you shift all to the right so A is now B, B is C, etc....A is now Names...it will not work.

Comment: Modify it to `COLUMN ()-1`.